# ZeroMQ в PHP без переключения контекста?

Tags: php, сокет

Возьмем пример из документации ZeroMQ

```
<?php
/*
*  Hello World server
*  Binds REP socket to tcp://*:5555
*  Expects "Hello" from client, replies with "World"
* @author Ian Barber <ian(dot)barber(at)gmail(dot)com>
*/

$context = new ZMQContext(1);

//  Socket to talk to clients
$responder = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_REP);
$responder->bind("tcp://*:5555");

while (true) {
//  Wait for next request from client
$request = $responder->recv();
printf ("Received request: [%s]\n", $request);

//  Do some 'work'
sleep (1);

//  Send reply back to client
$responder->send("World");
}
```

В этом случае исполнение кода прекратится на строчке

```
$request = $responder->recv();
```

**Вопрос:** как использовать ZeroMQ в PHP без переключения контекста? (если нет запроса, то просто игнорируем код, связанный с ZeroMQ)